# Uploading other users' videos onto my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

Can multiple users upload their own personal videos from their mobile phone, to my business YouTube Channel via my website?  Firstly is this allowed (I don't want them to upload onto their own Channels) and secondly, how could I afterwards pull the right videos to stream on my YouTube player embedded on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I can't think of a reason why this should not be allowed.

I would build an application which is running on the server and has access to your YT channel. You can achieve this by using the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started). This way, people have to upload videos to your server, which itself uploads them to YT. The advantage of this method is, that your application (and therefore you) can decide who has access to what specific action (e.g. uploading, deleting, making playlists, etc.)

Comment: Sorry if this is too 'simple' as I'm far from being any kind of expert!  IS there a way to not use my own server for uploads, and have them directly upload to YouTube?

Comment: And if Yes, then I believe I could only stream the videos later, and not download to edit etc?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's possible to upload directly to YT when you're not a channel admin.

Comment: OK, just want to make sure I understand correctly... so to re-phrase...  a user comes onto my website.  They record a video from a function in my website, click upload.  So they can either: 1) login to their own YouTube account to upload to their Channel, or 2) upload the video to my server (from which I can choose to upload to my website's YouTube channel.     Does this mean I cannot get them to upload it directly from their mobile phone, from my website, to my website's YouTube channel?